# Delete duplicate rows and leave specific row behind

Tags: excel, duplicates, vba

I have date in the following example format:

ABC 001

ABC 002

ABC 003

ABC 004

I want to remove duplcate rows in column A BUT leave the line with the highest value in column B (in this case 004). A simple duplicate removal doesn't give me the control on which value is not deleted (unless I'm missing something).

This is part of a larger VBA code and therefore, I'd like to do it via VBA. I greatly appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Is the second column numeric or text??

Comment: If you can sort the data, sort column B w/ the largest @ the top and then you can use remove duplicates to get your expected results.  (assuming that column B is numeric).

Comment: Yes, @Gary'sStudent, the secomd column is numeric.

Comment: @sous2817: I had the same thought but hadn't gotten that far yet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that column B contains numeric values, then you can use the code below to remove all non-max-duplicates. This works however the data is sorted since it loads the information into an array that keeps track of which value from column B is the largest.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim NonDupArr() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim EntryFound As Boolean

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    'Reads range into an array and retains the records with the largest value
    For i = 2 To sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Step 1
        EntryFound = False

        'If first entry
        If i = 2 Then
            ReDim Preserve NonDupArr(1 To 2, 1 To 1)
            NonDupArr(1, 1) = sht.Cells(i, 1).Value
            NonDupArr(2, 1) = sht.Cells(i, 2).Value
        'For all other entries
        Else
            'Loops through array to see if entry already exist
            For j = LBound(NonDupArr, 2) To UBound(NonDupArr, 2)
                If sht.Cells(i, 1).Value = NonDupArr(1, j) Then
                    'If enty exists it replaces the value from column B if larger than
                    'the entry allready in the array
                    If sht.Cells(i, 2).Value > NonDupArr(2, j) Then
                        NonDupArr(2, j) = sht.Cells(i, 2).Value
                    End If
                    EntryFound = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j

            'If no entry were found it will be added to the array
            If Not EntryFound Then
                ReDim Preserve NonDupArr(1 To 2, 1 To UBound(NonDupArr, 2) + 1)
                NonDupArr(1, UBound(NonDupArr, 2)) = sht.Cells(i, 1).Value
                NonDupArr(2, UBound(NonDupArr, 2)) = sht.Cells(i, 2).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    'Loops through the sheet and removes all rows that doesn't match rows in the array
    For i = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        'Searches for match in array
        For j = LBound(NonDupArr, 2) To UBound(NonDupArr, 2)
            'If this is not the largest entry then the row is removed
            If sht.Cells(i, 1).Value = NonDupArr(1, j) And sht.Cells(i, 2).Value <> NonDupArr(2, j) Then
                sht.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Seren. I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes.